# Show JPane depending on condition NetBeans GUI builder

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I have a form(JFrame) that has a two-stage process of completing it: first user selects something, second depending on what was selected either Button or TextField is shown.

For example, suppose I want to get a file from a user. I want to give the user an option of either typing fileName with the TextField or a Browse button that would pop up FileChooser. However, I want the Button or TextField to show up at the **same** position within JFrame.

SetVisible(True/False) wouldn't work because I want either one of them to show in the same place - NetBeans just wouldn't let me put to Swing objects in the same place.

Here is a picture example:

http://postimg.org/image/3n2y3gpvj/

How would I do it in NetBeans GUI builder(since I can't modify the initComponents())?

Comment: what layout are you using? you can right click and `customize code` in component. i don't understand very well your question

Comment: I am using free layout. If you take a look at the picture, I have Button above TextField; however, I want one of them to become visible at the same place when user selects comboBoxes above. NetBeans wouldn't let me put two things at the same place and then use logic to make the hidden/visible

Comment: i'd rather recommend to not use free design cause when you want to maximize your frame or add components in runtime wont work properly.. if you use for example FlowLayout in that JPanel when you put it `setVisible(false)` then the other will be in that place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GriBagLayout, placing components in same cell.
[image: GridBagLayout]